# Swift – Instantiating a navigation controller without storyboards in App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I'm rebuilding an app without storyboards and the part of it that I'm having the most trouble with is navigating view-to-view programatically. Few things are written out there which don't use storyboards, so finding an answer for this has been tough.

My problem is pretty simple. I have my `ViewController` and my `SecondViewController` and I want to push from the former to the latter.

In `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Then in `ViewController.swift`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        startFinishButton.setTitle("Begin", forState: .Normal)
        startFinishButton.addTarget(self, action: "moveToSecondViewController", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview <*> startFinishButton
    }

    func moveToSecondViewController(sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = SecondViewController()
        println(self.navigationController) // returns nil
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Printing `self.navigationController` returns nil. I've tried doing:

`var navController = UINavigationController()` when the `ViewController` class is created (but outside of ViewDidLoad, right under the class declaration) and done the push using the `navController` var but that hasn't worked.

I'm thinking maybe the solution is to create a navigation controller in App Delegate that the whole app would use, I guess as a global variable?

My hope is that this post can serve many others who are new to Swift and want to remove storyboards from their app.

Thanks for taking a look and for your help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**In Swift 3**

Place this code inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in AppDelegate class.

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let mainController = MainViewController() as UIViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainController)
navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: What is you have a custom navigationController?

Comment: In Xcode 11 and Swift 5 you need to make this in SceneDelegate.swift and not in AppDelegate.swift - the things changes a little bit.

Answer (score 18):

***In AppDelegate***

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navController: UINavigationController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    navController = UINavigationController()
    var viewController: ViewController = ViewController()
    self.navController!.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    self.window!.rootViewController = navController

    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

***In ViewController***

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "FirstVC"

    var startFinishButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    startFinishButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
    startFinishButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    startFinishButton.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    startFinishButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(startFinishButton)
}

func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println("Button tapped")
    let vc = SecondViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Why are you setting viewcontroller to a uiviewcontroller rather than my first view controller, ViewController.swift?

Comment: @ZackShapiro, I edited my answer. I have created an example in Xcode with this code and it works.

Comment: One last question, how do I use `navController` in my various view controllers to push/pop/etc?

Comment: @ZackShapiro, I edited my answer to explain you how to use navController. Please accept my answer if you find it correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 and Xcode 13 there is a SceneDelegate along with the AppDelegate.   So now to completely remove the storyboard from a project and embed the view controller in a navigation controller do the following:

1. Delete the actual storyboard in the Project Navigator
2. Select the project in the Project Navigator, select Target and then the General tab, then delete the storyboard from Main Interface
3. In the info.plist file delete the storyboard from:

   Application Scene Manifest > Scene Configuration > Application Session Role > Item 0 (Default Configuration) > Storyboard Name

Then in the scene delegate change the scene function to look like this:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController())
    window.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```