# Trying to Embed VC into NavigationVC from performActionFor shortcutItem via 3d touch on App icon

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, 3dtouch

I have an app that is using 3d touch to jump to a certain VC in my app. The issue is that when the app is launched normally, all of my VC's are embedded into a Navigation View Controller. But since I am skipping the launch sequence and jumping right into a VC, the VC that I jump to isn't embedded into the Nav VC.

Here is what I am trying in the App Delegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    guard TouchActions(rawValue: shortcutItem.type) != nil else {
        print("3d not working")
        completionHandler(false)
        return
    }

   print("3d touch workig")

    let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let addPersonVC : AddPersonViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddPerson") as! AddPersonViewController
    // pass the stack to the addPersonVC
    addPersonVC.coreDataStack = coreDataStack


    let navController:UINavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navController") as! UINavigationController
    navController.pushViewController(addPersonVC, animated: true)


   // self.window? = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    completionHandler(true)
}
```

This code works, but you when I try to leave this VC, the app just sits there unresponsive. I some how need to embedded addPersonVC into the main Nav VC that is set up in storyboard. (The embedded navigation controller was set up in storyboard, incase that matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option1: Add a `Storyboard Identifier` to your `UINavigationController` , and instantiate the `UINavigationController` instead.

Option2: Delete the `UINavigationController` from storyboard. Just [initialize a new UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956476/swift-instantiating-a-navigation-controller-without-storyboards-in-app-delegat) by code and set the `rootView` programatically.

I am not a Swift developer, but since you don't see the examples I wrote I did some quick pasting to help you understand the basics, try this code:

```
let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let addPersonVC : AddPersonViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddPerson") as! AddPersonViewController
    // pass the stack to the addPersonVC
    addPersonVC.coreDataStack = coreDataStack

let navController:UINavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navController") as! UINavigationController
    navController.viewControllers = [addPersonVC]


    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: I tried to do you first option, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions? I updated my question above to show you what I am trying.

Comment: @icekomo I am not a Swift programmer, however, The solution was in option2 for Swift. Your updated code seems to be totally messed up now. You need to add the **AddPersonViewController** as **rootViewController** to your UINavigationController. Also you can not "Push" the "addPersonVC", you need to **self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController** , check option2 link as I said for Swift example you will see the answer there m8.

Comment: @icekomo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753925/set-initial-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate-swift you can check here for another answer too for Swift.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated what I am using, it's giving me a fatal error now: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I'm not 100% that I am using my NavigationController from the storyboard ID correctly. I know you're not a Swift guy, so thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @icekomo Check my updated code to get a hint, let me know if it works. Beware, I maybe have some parsing errors you can fix that in Xcode if so.

Comment: that seems to out it in a navController inside maybe another NavController. WIth your code, how does it know that it should use my NavController from the storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135005/discussion-between-sneak-and-icekomo).