# Dismiss only presented view controller not the whole navigation stack Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

I have a tab bar controller. In that the first tab is a navigation controller. Lets call it controller A. I am then pushing another view controller on it. Lets call it controller B. 
After that I am presenting view controller C from View controller B. Now I want to dismiss only the view controller B.

Tab Bar - A(Navigation Controller's root vc) -> Push VC -> B -> Present VC -> C

A to B is going using `self.navigationController.pushViewController(animated: true, completion: nil)`

B to C is going like this
`let vc = CViewController()
 vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
 self.present(vc,animated: true,completion: nil)`

Now When I use 
`self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` in View Controller C. It goes back to the root view controller i.e vc A. I want it to go to VC B.

[image: Video of issue]

Comment: When you call self.dismiss, you are not calling dismiss on C, but on B. Have you tried popViewController?

Comment: I have written the dismiss code in vc C. And pop view controller won't work because C is presented modally not pushed

Comment: I presume you have tried "vc.dismiss()"  instead of self.dismiss() ?

Comment: Yes already tried that

Comment: can you add screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: I am doing everything programmatically. No storyboards

Comment: Question updated with a video of what's happening @KetanParmar

Comment: @OrionCygnus Please check the video

Comment: are you embedding navigation controller with your view controller B? can you show me your hierarchy like tab - nav - vcA - nav etc?

Comment: The animation you posted does not appear to match your description, as the first "push" animation covers the Tab Bar -- which would mean the TabBarController is embedded in a Navigation Controller, not the other way around. Since you are not using Storyboards, try to post the code for a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of thought, I replicated what you were trying to do and figured out the problem is not with calling dismiss. It is with the way you called that View Controller in the first place. Change your "B to C" code a little bit.

Instead of:

> let vc = CViewController()
>
> vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
>
> self.present(vc,animated: true,completion: nil)

use:

```
let sb : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "C")
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You would have to specify the identifier of your view controller in the storyboard, (Storyboard ID)

Now when you call self.dismiss(), it should only close C.
I have tested this on my computer with Xcode 11.1.

Comment: refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160137/how-to-create-viewcontrollers-without-storyboard-and-set-one-as-delegate-of-the

Comment: That talks about pushing view controller. My issue is with presenting modally.